# Count of On-Going Transaction in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this table:

| book_name | borrow_date | return_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-03 |
| B | 2022-08-03 | 2022-09-01 |
| C | 2022-08-15 | 2022-09-25 |
| D | 2022-09-15 | 2022-09-18 |
| E | 2022-09-17 | 2022-10-15 |

And table of first date of the month

| summary_month |
| --- |
| 2022-08-01 |
| 2022-09-01 |
| 2022-10-01 |

I would like to count how many books are **currently** borrowed based on the summary_month. The result I am looking for is:

| summary_month | count_book | list_book |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 3 | A,B,C |
| 2022-09-01 | 4 | B,C,D,E |
| 2022-10-01 | 1 | E |

I am stuck with only able to aggregate them based on the borrowed date with query:

```
count(distinct case when summary_month = date_trunc(borrow_date,month) then book_name end) count_book
```

Is it possible to get the result I am hoping for? Really need anyone's help and advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can work:

```sql
with 
input as (
  select 'A' book_name,     cast('2022-08-01' as date) borrow_date ,    cast('2022-08-03' as date) return_date union all
  select 'B',   '2022-08-03',   '2022-09-01' union all
  select 'C',   '2022-08-15',   '2022-09-25' union all
  select 'D',   '2022-09-15',   '2022-09-18' union all
  select 'E',   '2022-09-17',   '2022-10-15'
),

list_month as (
  select distinct 
    * except(days_borrowed), 
    date_trunc(days_borrowed, month) as month 
  from input, 
  unnest(generate_date_array(borrow_date, return_date)) as days_borrowed
)

select 
  month, 
  count(distinct book_name) as count_distinct_book,
  string_agg(distinct book_name) as book_name_list
from list_month
group by 1 
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option

```
select summary_month, 
  count(distinct book_name) as count_book, 
  string_agg(book_name) as list_book
from your_table, unnest(generate_date_array(
  date_trunc(borrow_date, month), 
  date_trunc(return_date, month), 
  interval 1 month)
) as summary_month
group by summary_month
```

if applied to sample data in your question -output is

[image]